# Sum of array of integers (strings?) without losing decimals

Tags: javascript, jquery-1.7

**Given**: I have elements with values of <strike>integers</strike> floats (thank you, Pointy) up to two decimal places (such as: 1.50 and 2.25).

**Goal**: Collect the values of several elements and add them together. (such as: 1.50 + 2.25 = 3.75 )

**Code**:

```
$(".quantity").keyup(function(){      
  var sum = 0.00;
  var subTotals = document.getElementsByClassName("sub-total")

  $.each(subTotals, function(){
    sum += $(this).val() << 0
  });
  $("#products_revenue_income").val(sum)
});
```

**Issue**: I'm used to Ruby, so I presumed that iterating over an array of [1.5, 2.25] you could add the elements together with `+=`, to get `3.75`, but my return value was `01.502.25`,  appearing to (1) add a zero to the left and (2) treat the values as a string. When I added the shift operator `<<`, it removed the left zero and treated the values like integers again, but it rounded the total, so my return value is  `3`.

**What I've tried**: I've tried using `parseFloat($(this).val()).toFixed(2)` within the block to make sure each value is treated as an integer but it doesn't appear to have any effect on the result.

**Tech**: jQuery version: 1.7.1.

Thank you for your time Let me know if you require any additional context.

Comment: `1.50` and `2.25` are not integers.

Comment: Also note that as you sum your non-integer values, it's quite possible that you'll see floating-point issues.

Comment: Tip: [Don't use jQuery for math](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/183280)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because jQuery's `val()` method returns the `value` property of the matched element which is a string type. This means you're falling into the string concatenation trap (`"1"` + `"1"` = `"11"`). You can convert your value into a number using a Unary plus (`+`):

```
sum += +$(this).val();
```

Also worth noting that `value` is a native property of `this`, so you can drop the jQuery wrapper and method here altogether:

```
sum += +this.value;
```

Answer (score 3):

The jQuery method .val() will return a string-like object, so to convert it to a float to make your maths work OK you can use parseFloat:

```
sum += parseFloat($(this).val())
```

MDN docs for parseFloat:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat

Example:

```
subTotals = [1.1, 2.2]
sum = 0

$.each(subTotals, function(idx, num){
    sum += parseFloat(num)
})

console.log(sum) // Will print 3.3
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/sifriday/7q4qe4L3/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `val()` returns a string. Instead of shift, convert the values. The cleanest and simplest way to do this is by subtracting zero from the value.

```
$(".quantity").keyup(function(){      
  var sum = 0.00;
  var subTotals = document.getElementsByClassName("sub-total")

  $.each(subTotals, function(){
    sum += $(this).val()-0
  });
  $("#products_revenue_income").val(sum)
});
```

This of course assumes that the values will *always* be numeric.